# PHP openssl_encrypt allowing 64 bytes secret key for AES-256-CBC but not in JAVA

Tags: php, php-openssl

I have a secret key and IV using which I generated corresponding SHA-256 hashes.

Hash of secret key is : 
`secret_key_hash = 76cb135fbba7e3db44c8bfe7428d7d512e6a9291a39cb7a8fe16e246ad82e99d`
Hash of IV is : 
`iv_hash = bc8805b0e87e3dec`

When I run php function:

```
<?php
$secret_key_hash = "76cb135fbba7e3db44c8bfe7428d7d512e6a9291a39cb7a8fe16e246ad82e99d";
$iv_hash = "bc8805b0e87e3dec";
echo openssl_encrypt("a", "AES-256-CBC", $secret_key_hash, 0, $iv_hash);
```

it returns encrypted string as `1Ti9PQqt0xMzjhJLv7KO6A==`

[PHP code demo](https://ideone.com/AW8IPP)

The problem is when I run the same encryption in my java implementation/ or any online AES encrypter it says secret_key size is 64 bytes, but it should be 32 bytes for 256 bit encryption.

I tried all possible cases, like converting the hashes to base64, truncating the hash to 32 bytes but unable to get the correct encrypted string like in php.

Here is my attempt of implementing same function in java

```
private static String openssl_encrypt(String data, String secretKey, String iv) throws Exception {
    Cipher ciper = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec secretSpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes(), 0, 16);
    ciper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretSpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] encryptedCiperBytes = ciper.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedCiperBytes);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    openssl_encrypt("a", "76cb135fbba7e3db44c8bfe7428d7d512e6a9291a39cb7a8fe16e246ad82e99d", "bc8805b0e87e3dec");
}
```

But this doesn't work as it says Invalid AES key length 64 bytes.

Can someone help me find out where I am going wrong?

Comment: You've tagged as PHP and shown PHP code so I presume you want to change the PHP implementation to match the Java one. Can you please edit the question and share the code attempt that doesn't work together with some sample desired output?

Comment: Also, `76cb135fbba7e3db44c8bfe7428d7d512e6a9291a39cb7a8fe16e246ad82e99d` looks like an hex dump of a **32-byte** hash :-?

Comment: Ok sharing java snippet.

Comment: `openssl_encrypt` does not use a 64 bytes key for AES-256. Instead, it simply truncates the key by taking only the first 32 bytes. Therefore, the same ciphertext will result for the posted PHP code if `$secret_key_hash = '76cb135fbba7e3db44c8bfe7428d7d51'` is used.

Comment: Worth noting that what you call a "key hash" is almost 100% just the human readable (i.e. hex-encoded) representation of a raw binary 32-bit key - the correct keysize for AES-256 - and it's just being misused.